# I'm not findig the element that I want

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm creating a roblox bot and for this I'm using "requests" lib, but I can't get the text in html, instead of it, I get "[<Element div at 0x2621f513b80>]", how can I solve this? Here's the code:

```
from lxml import html
    import requests
    for e in range(0,1):
        page = requests.get("https://www.roblox.com/catalog/138932314/Dominus-Aureus")
        hTml = html.fromstring(page.text)
        clean_hTml = hTml.xpath("//div[@class='icon-text-wrapper clearfix icon-robux-price-container']")
    print(clean_hTml)
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div class="icon-text-wrapper clearfix icon-robux-price-container">
                                                <span class="icon-robux-16x16 wait-for-i18n-format-render"></span>

                                                <span class="text-robux-lg wait-for-i18n-format-render">1,629,999</span>
                                        </div>
```

(Obs: I want to get this "1,629,999")

Comment: You can surely navigate through the div element

Comment: How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use text() method to extract the data.

clean_hTml = `hTml.xpath("//div[@class='icon-text-wrapper clearfix icon-robux-price-container']/span/text()")`

Comment: Glad to help. Thank you.